# Override a value generated by a sequence in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

What happens when we try to override a value generated by a sequence? Also how can the value be replaced.

For example if an Employees table has EMP_ID as the primary key which is generated by a sequence such as

EMP_ID
100
102
104
106

What happens if we try to replace 100 with 101 and how can we replace the value?

Comment: You can certainly update EMP_ID with whatever value you want.
But if you choose a value that will later be generated by the sequence, you will get a PK value violation on the second insert.  And if you choose a value that has already been used then the update will fail with a PK violation.  What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: i want to know if a particular value that is generated by the sequence can be replaced just by using a UPDATE query or any additional steps need to be followed. In the example provided the ID's are generated using a sequence and i want to only replace 100 with 101

Comment: UPDATE DML will do it.  But keep in mind what will happen if that emp_id is a foreign key in some other table; that will cause data integrity constraint violations since the value in the foreign key will no longer match the PK on the employee table.

Answer (score 0):

To your basic question, once a column is populated, there is nothing inherently to prevent you from updating it simply because it was initially populated with a value from a sequence.  Remember, a sequence is nothing but a source of generated numbers.  Oracle doesn't give a flying fig that you *just happen* to be using to populate a column - PK or not.  That said, you need to heed what the others have said, and give some serious - and I mean *SERIOUS* thought as to why you want to do this.  The very definition and purpose of a PK is such that there should never be any reason to change it. The very fact that it is being populated by the value from a sequence would indicate that the PK has no business meaning at all, and is merely an arbitrary identifier for that row.   If you have a legitimate need to change it, then you (the designers) have made a poor choice of a PK.